# TextView/editText value change

Tags: android, textview, int, android-edittext

I've a button that when pressed changes the value of a TextView in a separate activity displaying an EditText amount by 1 `--` however when it only works once, then it won't work again unless I put in a new editText value then it only works once, again.

so If I enter `10` then `onClick .Text--` it will take it to `9` then if I `onClick .Text--`
again it will still display `9`. Maybe you can see what I'm doing wrong?

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
             pref = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);{

        CaAdd.amnt.setText(String.valueOf(CaAdd.amountt-1));
        newone = Integer.toString(CaAdd.amountt-1);
        Editor editor = pref.edit();
        res = "You have"  +" " + (String.valueOf(CaAdd.amountt-1))+" " + "Life left!";
        editor.putString("new",newone);
        editor.commit();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), res ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The activity `CaAdd` holding the TextView and EditText:

```
    public void onClick(View v){


        Editor editor = pref.edit();

amountt++;
amountText = Integer.toString(amountt);
amountedit.setHint(amountText);
amnt.setText(amountText);



editor.putString("numbers", amountText);
editor.commit();





    }
});
ImageButton decrease = (ImageButton)mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.decrease);
decrease.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v){




        Editor editor = pref.edit();
      amountt--;
      amountText = Integer.toString(amountt);
      amountedit.setHint(amountText);
      amnt.setText(amountText);
      amount = amnt.getText().toString();
      editor.putString("numbers", amountText);
      editor.commit();

    }
         });
```

EDIT: like this?

```
     pref = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);{
  int   Am =    pref.getInt("numbers", Integer.valueOf(CaAdd.amountt));
CaAdd.amnt.setText(Am);
  Am--;

         pill = Integer.toString(Am);

        Editor editor = pref.edit();
        res = "You have"  +" " + (String.valueOf(CaAdd.amountt-1))+" " + "Life left!";
        editor.putString("new",pill);
        editor.commit();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), res ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you save the variable for increasing the decreasing value.
after onclick you are getting value from edittext and storing but that value you are decrementing is `amountt` variable. you need to get the value from preference and decrease it ,display it and save to preference

Comment: Thanks buddy, but I'm confused, which should I change? I thought I was saving the string value of `amountt` with increase and decrease then decrementing the same int?(`CaAdd.amountt`). Do I perhaps `pref.getString("numbers",amountText); then decrease that? I think I've tried that but I can not `--` a string only an int.

Comment: instead of variable direclty read value form prefernce, decrease it and display it and save afterwards

Comment: Bah, I still can't get it would you kindly show me some sample  code of what you mean?